# Creating R loop to paste together elements of vector while dropping previous elements of the vector

Tags: r, loops

Imagine I have a character vector like this:

```
mychars <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
```

I would like to write a loop (I imagine a for loop) that returns a list of character vectors with each given i'th element of the vector, followed by all **subsequent** elements, separated by "+":

```
"a b + c + d + e"
"b c + d + e"
"c d + e"
"d e"
```

Ideally the loop would be structured to accommodate character vectors of different lengths. E.g., if:

```
mychars <- c("a", "b", "c")
```

Then it would return:

```
"a b + c"
"b c"
```

Any ideas would be appreciated. If there's a term/name for this kind of looping process (where earlier elements are dropped on subsequent iterations), I'd also appreciate knowing it so I can learn more about it on my own.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R function that does what the question asks for.

```
fun <- function(x){
  n <- length(x)
  if(n > 0 && nchar(x) > 0){
    y <- character(n - 1)
    for(i in seq.int(n - 1)){
      y[i] <- paste(x[i], paste(x[(i + 1):n], collapse = " + "))
    }
  } else y <- NULL
  y
}

mychars1 <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
mychars2 <- c("a", "b", "c")

fun(mychars1)
fun(mychars2)
fun("")
```

Much simpler but returns an empty `list()` in the case of an input of length 0:

```
fun2 <- function(x){
  n <- length(x)
  sapply(seq_along(x)[-n], function(i){
    paste(x[i], paste(x[(i + 1):n], collapse = " + "))
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt (edit: now slightly simplified):

```
mychars <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")

fun1 <- function(mychars){
  out <- list()
  
  for(i in 1:length(mychars)-1){
    out[i] <- paste(mychars[i], paste0(mychars[(i+1):length(mychars)], collapse = " + "), sep = " ")
  }
  
  return(out)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this but simoncolumbus got there first. It can probably be made shorter, but I think this is clear and reasonably easy to debug, or to adapt if the requirements change.

```
oneplus <- function (x)
{
  paste(x[1], paste(x[2:length(x)], collapse=" + "))
}

allplus <- function (v)
{
  res <- list()
  for (i in 1:(length(v) - 1)) {
    res <- c(res, oneplus(v[i:length(v)]))
  }

  return (res)
}

allplus(c("a", "b", "c"))
```